# Linq to SQL order by aggregate

Tags: linq-to-sql, aggregate

I have a very simple grouping and aggregation problem in LINQ to SQL that I just can't figure out, and it is driving me mad.

I've simplified things into this example:

class Customer {
   public Guid Id;
   public String Name;
}

class Order {
   public Guid Customer_Id;
   public double Amount;
}

How do I get a list of customers ordered by the number of orders they have? And on the total amount they have purchased for?

Comment: Wow... some of these answers are highly over complicated. You can do this in one line by chaining a couple of simple methods if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var qry1 = from c in db.Customers
           join o in db.Orders on c.Id equals o.Customer_Id into orders
           orderby orders.Count()
           select c;

var qry2 = from c in db.Customers
           join o in db.Orders on c.Id equals o.Customer_Id into orders
           orderby orders.Sum(o => o.Amount)
           select c;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return dataContext.Customers.OrderBy(cust => cust.Orders.Count)
    .ThenBy(cust => cust.Orders.Sum(order => order.Amount))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

By number of orders:

```
var customers = (from c in db.Customers
                 select new 
                  {
                    c.Name, 
                    OrderCount = c.Orders.Count()
                  }).OrderBy(x => x. OrderCount);
```

By total amount purchased:

```
var customers = (from c in db.Customers
                 select new 
                  {
                    c.Name, 
                    Amount = (from order in c.Orders
                              select order.Amount).Sum()
                  }).OrderBy(x => x.Amount);
```